# How to generate navigation tree in doxygen output?

Tags: documentation, javadoc, doxygen

If you've used javadoc and then come to doxygen, you may know what I mean when I say I miss the hierarchical (frame-based) view that made jumping from class to class and method to method easy.  (For those who haven't seen it, imagine a tree-navigator in an IDE or over a filesystem).

How can I get Doxygen to include a navigation tree, if it's even possible?

A [similar question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165451/suggest-a-good-doxygen-stylesheet) in October, but that was just about stylesheet alternatives and only one turned up.  I think I'm looking for something more major.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that all you need to do to get the tree on the left in Quinn's example is setting GENERATE_TREEVIEW to YES in the config file.

Comment: Hey, Dimitri! Welcome Stack Overflow, and thanks for writing Doxygen! :-)

Answer (score 4):

At a basic level, Doxygen output is what it is, and I don't think there's "a better way to view" static HTML content. I think what you want is for Doxygen to produce HTML output that is more similar to Javadoc, which has both pros and cons. (The biggest drawback is that it's unlikely to happen, due to the effort involved and the broad user base.)

I manage [a project that is documented using Doxygen](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/), and I'm not sure to what degree my config uses the Doxygen defaults, but I get a sections in the left frame for a flat class list and a class hierarchy. Also, since I have diagrams enabled, the Graphical Class Hierarchy is a fairly quick way to jump to where I want. I haven't delved into Doxygen modules, so I don't have any experience with whether that might segment things similar to how Javadoc does with packages.

Comment: I just realized I hadn't linked directly to the Doxygen config file I'm using. Here it is: http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/chsvn/CHDataStructures/doxygen/Doxyfile